# Best practices for certificates in docker

Tags: ssl, docker

If I have a docker application (J2EE web applications) meeting the following conditions:

- there are multiple containers to be deployed (from the same image) on separate hosts which will then communicate with each other over SSL/TLS - so the containers would need their own SSL certificates, and need to trust the certificates of the other containers
- these containers will additionally make HTTPS calls to other external URLs - so the certificates of these servers also need to be trusted. These external URL are not known at deployment time, so the certificates need to be imported separately
- the application being a J2EE web application uses java keystore and truststore for the certificates

Given this, how should the certificates be made available to the servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: 2018-02**

Docker Swarm allows secrets keeping. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/
This is however not supported in non Swarm deployments. One hacky way to get around this is to deploy to only 1 node as a Swarm.

**Previous answer:**

Docker doesn't currently have a way to handle secrets (it's on their road map). There's a long running thread over at Docker. It lists many ways that people use to import secrets into containers.
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13490

Some people use HashiCorp's Vault, others encrypt secrets on the host (env vars) or in a docker volume (that's what my team does). Containers can decrypt them when they are started (ENTRYPOINT/COMMAND). To add secrets at run time, you can create a custom container that does just that (accepts a http request and store it in a truststore). Just a suggestion amongst many that you'll see in the link above.

Answer (score -1):

Application should handle this internally:

If you have a java app running inside a docker container you can use the java keystore (just then add the other containers pem's to the applications keystore in the Dockerfile)

```
# import my domaincert
COPY homelinux.org.pem /tmp/homelinux.org.pem
RUN /usr/bin/keytool -import -alias homelinux.org -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -file /tmp/homelinux.org.pem -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

I have ~15 containers on *.homelinux.org via dyndns and a
*.homelinux.org self-signed domain certificate `(dnsname=*.homelinux.org)` so the containers can use ssl between them fine.